# How to change default <main> element generated by TailwindCSS installation on Ruby on Rails?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, erb

Apparently, if one installs TailwindCSS on Ruby on Rails, this will generate a html  element with a series of classes that centers in a very strange way all the views you have in the app.

`<main class="container mx-auto mt-28 px-5 flex">`

The above element appears in every view after one installs TailwindCSS. What would be the best approach to customize/remove this element?

Would be also grateful if anyone can also explain why they choose to spawn this element. On their github, someone created an issue about this, but their response wasn't very clear to me: " is added in order to centralize the content". Thank you.

Comment: The `<main>` element is where the centralized (important/relevant) content on the page goes. I'm sure that's why it's added. As for how to customize it, I'd look at the docs. That said, It seems like there would be a template where you could adjust those classes. Seems like it's a start page like many frameworks.

Comment: `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

Answer (score 0):

Really not sure what the issue is here, [the main tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) has a clear semantic, classically people would have things like a "container" or "content" div but now they can use `main` instead, Rails adds it in order to give a top level tag for styling/containing the main content of a page, feel free to restyle it however you please, or remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The issue is that Tailwind installation generated the classes you can see in the html code snippet above. Being such a neophyte, my problem was actually finding where the <main> element resides, but I was also curious about why Tailwind has this approach and how does applying a 28 top margin makes sense, as it looks quite strange, especially if the app was already partially developed.

Comment: Just [a dev choice of the `tailwindcss-rails` authors](https://github.com/rails/tailwindcss-rails/pull/106)